# How to pass jmeter response data (ex: getting response 295 without any lable) to next http request url path/body

Tags: jmeter

How to pass jmeter response data (ex: getting response 295 without any lable) to next http request url path/body. This 3 digits/4 digits number is dynamically generated for every run and this value i have to use it for next API calls. Since this value is not having any lable/attribute name not sure how to extract this value. Please suggest.[image: responsedata]

Comment: Use the expression (.+) as Regular Expression.

Comment: Thanks @Adnan. Working fine, able to extract the value by using reg expression (.+).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to extract a single numeric value, the relevant regular expression will be as simple as `(\d+)`. See [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet) for quick reference.

If in future you will need a regular expression which return the **whole response** (including line breaks, special characters, whatever), as per [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter) article it will be something like `(?s)(^.*)`

Answer (score 2):

Regular Expression Configuration:

```
Reference Name: anything
Regular Expression: (.+)
Template: $1$
Match No.(O for Random): 1
```

The Reference name should be passed as the variable in the next HTTP request URL path/body.

Screenshot from `Regex Test` in `View Results Tree`.

[image]